# fo:page-sequence two column not appearing in output XSL-FO

Tags: xslt-1.0, xsl-fo, antenna-house

I wanted to try a two column layout for a small table. I copied the existing simple-page-master and added `column-count="2"`. (I'm not including headers or footers for brevity.) The template works as expected if I delete the `fo:page-sequence` and `fo:flow` but otherwise I'm getting nothing in my output. I tried substituting another template for numIndex and that also fails.

I'm using Antenna House. As always, I appreciate any suggestions.

```
<fo:simple-page-master master-name="body-page-two-col" xsl:use-attribute-sets="odd-page-atts">
    <fo:region-body region-name="region-body" xsl:use-attribute-sets="body-atts" column-count="2"/>
</fo:simple-page-master>

<xsl:attribute-set name="odd-page-atts">
        <xsl:attribute name="page-height">11in</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="page-width">8.5in</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="margin-top">1.5pc</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="margin-bottom">1.5pc</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="margin-left">1in</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="margin-right">.5in</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:attribute-set>

<xsl:attribute-set name="body-atts">
        <xsl:attribute name="margin-top">4.5pc</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="margin-bottom">4.5pc</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:attribute-set>

    <xsl:template name="numIndex">
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="body-page-two-col" initial-page-number="auto" format="1">
            <fo:flow flow-name="region-body">
<fo:block>
            <fo:table-and-caption>
                <fo:table-caption>
                    <fo:block>
                        <xsl:text>Numerical Index</xsl:text>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-caption>
                <fo:table>
                <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::dmodule/identAndStatusSection/dmAddress/dmIdent/dmCode"/><xsl:text>tbl-numidx001</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>
                    <fo:table-header>
                        <fo:table-row>
                                <fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:block font-size="11pt" font-style="italic" >                            
                                    <fo:retrieve-table-marker retrieve-class-name="continued-ni" retrieve-boundary-within-table="table"/>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                    </fo:table-header>
                    <fo:table-body>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:marker marker-class-name="continued-ni"/>
                                 <fo:marker marker-class-name="continued-ni">
                                    <fo:block text-align="center">Numerical Index&#160; (Continued)
                                    </fo:block>
                                 </fo:marker>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table border-bottom="solid" border-bottom-width=".5pt" 
                border-top="solid" border-top-width=".5pt" font-size="8pt" 
                margin-bottom="8pt" margin-left="3pt" margin-right="3pt" margin-top="8pt" 
                relative-position="static" space-after.maximum="12pt" space-after.minimum="12pt" 
                space-after.optimum="12pt" space-before.maximum="14pt" space-before.minimum="12pt" 
                space-before.optimum="12pt" span="all" table-layout="fixed" table-omit-header-at-break="false" 
                table-omit-footer-at-break="true" text-align="start" white-space-treatment="preserve" 
                width="3.0in" hyphenate="true" cols="4">
                    <fo:table-column column-number="1" column-width="30%"/>
                    <fo:table-column column-number="2" column-width="20%"/>
                    <fo:table-column column-number="3" column-width="20%"/>
                    <fo:table-column column-number="4" column-width="20%"/>
                    <fo:table-header>
                        <xsl:call-template name="NI-HEADER"/>
                    </fo:table-header>
                <fo:table-body>     
                    <xsl:call-template name="SortParts"/>
                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
            </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-body>
                </fo:table>
                </fo:table-and-caption>
                </fo:flow>
</fo:block>
                </fo:page-sequence>
        </xsl:template>
```

This is what calls numIndex:

```
<xsl:template match="illustratedPartsCatalog">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
            <xsl:call-template name="numIndex"/>
    </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want a table that flows into two columns within your regular one-column flow.  Since you're using AH Formatter, you can use a two-column `fo:block-container` to contain just the table. See https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf64/ahf-ext.html#axf.column-count.  However that's not going to get you your '(continued)' marker.  To do that, you could put the `fo:block-container` as the child of the `fo:table-cell` from the outer `fo:table`.

However, since I'm not at all sure that I do understand your requirement, could you do a simple graphic illustration of what you are looking for?

Also, if, as you show in your code sample, the `fo:simple-page-master` is outside any `xsl:template`, it will be ignored by the XSLT processor and will not appear in your FO file.

According to https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#stylesheet-element:

> an XSLT processor is always free to ignore such top-level elements, and must ignore a top-level element without giving an error if it does not recognize the namespace URI.

Comment: Actually, Tony that's what I want, and the index table is now in two columns. I need to span the title and continued markers but I think I can figure it out. I was going to try to implement this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461866/xsl-list-divided-into-columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461866/xsl-list-divided-into-columns) but the two-column container is working for me. Thank you!

Comment: Regarding the `fo:simple-page-master` is that syntax incorrect? The `fo:simple-page-master` was in a separate file with the other page sets (that gets called from the main .xsl file) and I wasn't going to bother with  `fo:page-sequence-master` and headers and footers until I had the two column format working.

Comment: The problem isn't the syntax, it's the position of the markup.  Since the `fo:simple-page-master` appears to be outside of any `xsl:template`, it won't end up in the result document.  The same is true for any non-XSLT element that's a child of `xsl:stylesheet`, so it has nothing to do with the correctness of your XSL-FO markup.

Comment: This worked great. On the last page there are only ten rows of the table and it's being split into two columns. Is there a way to keep all the rows in the first column?

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 problems:

1. You've specified `width="7.0in"` for the fo:table, so it won't fit inside a column that's narrower than that. Your columns are only 3.5" minus the column-gap between the columns (12pt if you don't specify otherwise). The table will flow to the first body page that's wide enough to accommodate them.
2. `template match="illustratedPartsCatalog"` first does an apply-templates. If that generates a page-sequence and doesn't close it, the `call-template name="numIndex"` will try to create a nested page-sequence and that won't work.

An FO template starts with a `</fo:layout-master-set>`.

Then there are two ways to proceed: you can use `template match="node"` to match each child of the root node in the XML, or you can use `xsl:call-template` commands. This gives you more flexibility, you can build a template that generates one page-sequence that contains more than one of the children of the root node.

So you could do this:

```
<xsl:call-template name="insertIllustratedPartsCatalog"/>
<xsl:call-template name="numIndex"/>
```

where `insertIllustratedPartsCatalog` creates a page-sequence for the parts catalog, and `numIndex` creates a page-sequence for the index.

(it's difficult to get more specific than that without seeing the whole FO template).

Comment: Thank you, I changed the width to 3 inches but nothing is still being displayed.

Comment: Thanks again, I added the block and same result. How do I know if the page-sequence has been closed from `illustratedPartsCatalog`?

Comment: If you use the Antennahouse GUI, you can do File->Save FO, this will save the result of the FO transformation. The Illustratedpartscatalog should contain only one page-sequence element, not nested page-sequence elements.

Comment: That is the problem, in the FO the Numerical Index table is there, but its page-sequence is nested inside the IllustratedPartsCatalog page sequence. I'm going to try applying the two column format to illustratedPartsCatalog and use spans. I don't know how to get the Numerical Index out of the illustratedPartsCatalog page sequence because it is generated from the tags of the illustratedPartsCatalog.

Comment: You can place `xsl:call-template name="numIndex"` anywhere in your FO template, no need to call it from inside the  IllustratedPartsCatalog template. You'll just need to adjust the XPath in NumIndex.

Comment: That's what I don't understand, what to hook the call to Numindex outside of IPC since it is dependent on IPC and shouid appear after the IPC.

Comment: `fo:flow` can directly contain `fo:table-and-caption`.  The allowed content of `fo:flow` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_flow) is "`(%block;)+`",  and `fo:table-and-caption` is one of the `%block;` FOs listed in Section 6.2, Formatting Object Content (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#d0e6532).

Comment: AH Formatter can handle nested `fo:page-sequence`.  See https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf64/ahf-ext.html#fo.page-sequence.  Whether or not using nested `fo:page-sequence` will produce the desired result is a different question.